# Getting the hex address of an instance in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to get the hex address of an instance object in the debug window of XCode via NSLog?

I have a set of NSArray and NSDictionary objects and I want to get the address of the instance, not the contents.

Trying [obj description] will tell me the contents but not address.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%p", objcObj);
```

Will print object's address

Comment: That'd be the long way around.  Just 'p objcObj' will work in the debugger.